# translate site based on select menu

Tags: laravel

Im studying about Laravel doing a simple blog and in the blog footer I createad a select menu for the user to select 1 of 3 languages (english, spanish and german). The goal is that if the user select english, all content of the site changes to englis, and the same for the other languages. But Im not understanding how to achieve this properly. If is necessary to use some translation API or if there is some package that allows to achieve this.

Do you know how this feature can be achieved?

Comment: How do you store different language contents? How do you get contents for output? Show some code you have already. You tagged `google-translate`: does it mean you are using google translate already?

Comment: Thanks, Im a beginner, for now I just have static html with the options of the languages. I dont have any server code for this, I put put that tag because maybe is necessary to use the API to achieve this since its necessary to translate the site to other languages.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to make some code and when stuck with something you post that part of code here for others to try to solve. I would suggest you to study Laravel first checking how to store data to database then how to output stored data to the page. If third party application is needed then study their documentation too. This is too broad asked this way. Also check here one phenomenal article of how to ask [perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). But also check the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on this site too. Good luck